# What is the limit of cabin baggage on Wizz Air flights?

Tags: luggage, wizz-air

What's the weight limit on Wizz Air, for cabin baggage?

I can't find anything about the weight on their website. I know that for Ryanair is 10kg, and EasyJet say they don't have a limit for weight.

Comment: Where are you flying? That might make a difference.

Answer (score 5):

As at October 4, 2012, [WizzAir](https://wizzair.com/en-GB/useful_information/baggage) implemented a new cabin baggage policy.  [Press release here](http://wizzair.com/en-GB/about_us/news/wizen124).

Now, you:

> "can travel with a free small cabin bag (up to 42x32x25cm) or pay a ₤9
>   online fee to bring a large cabin bag (up to 56x45x25cm) on board.
>   Goods purchased at the airport after security (an important source of
>   revenue for Wizz Air’s 81 airport partners) will continue to be
>   allowed in the cabin for free"

See the press release for the table showing the simple comparison.  There doesn't appear to be a weight limit at this time, but many airlines expect you to be able to lift it unaided into the cabin baggage compartments.

Comment: I'm flying from Paris to Warsaw,
I don't intend to make the bag that much heavier, it's just so i don't get neurotic on the 10kg! 
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

Their website clearly states checked baggage allowance.

> Due to health and safety reasons the weight of any one piece of checked-in baggage must not exceed 32 kilograms.

Source [Wizz Air Website](http://wizzair.com/en-GB/useful_information/baggage)

The same link also explains Cabin Baggage where there are no limits in weight but they do specify specific size dimensions of baggage.

> Wizz Air offers two cabin baggage options, but has a strict “one cabin baggage per passenger” policy. The difference between the options is the size.
>
> 1. Small cabin bag: If your cabin baggage is of size 42x32x25cm or smaller it can be taken onboard free of charge. It must fit under the
>      seat in front of you.
> 2. Large cabin bag: If your cabin baggage is larger than the dimensions of a small cabin bag but not exceeding 56x45x25cm, you can
>      take it onboard for a fee. It must fit in the overhead compartment.
>      You must be able to place it in the overhead compartment unassisted.

Comment: that's checked-in luggage, not 'cabin baggage' as the OP requested.

Comment: Apologies mis-read the question

Comment: @pnuts Comment removed :) new glasses ordered...

Answer (score 2):

The limit for the large cabin baggage is [10 kg](https://wizzair.com/en-GB/useful_information/baggage):

[image]

Visit site for further details.

Answer (score 0):

There is no weight limit, it just has to fulfil the Dimension criteria.

[WIZZ's](https://wizzair.com/en-gb/information-and-services/travel-information/baggage#before-october) website implicitly states that, while checked luggage can be max 32 kg, there's no limit for hand luggage

Starting on 29 October, however, the small and large hand bag categories will be merged into a single Hand bag category, which allows for 56x45x25 cm and a Maximum of 10 kg)