# What is the weight limit of a large cabin baggage on WizzAir?

Tags: luggage, hand-luggage, wizz-air

I'm paying for a large (56 x 45 x 25 cm) on-board luggage at WizzAir, but can't find the weight anywhere on their website.

I've been looking at other posts like [this one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35849/what-is-the-limit-of-cabin-baggage-on-wizz-air-flights) but it's seriously outdated (and doesn't give a concrete answer to the question) and wanted to know if anyone happened to know the actual numbers by any chance.

Comment: I'm sorry, but just because a post is old doesn't mean we need to create a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no weight limit, it just has to fulfil the Dimension criteria.

[WIZZ's](https://wizzair.com/en-gb/information-and-services/travel-information/baggage#before-october) website implicitly states that, while checked luggage can be max 32 kg, there's no limit for hand luggage

Starting on 29 October, however, the small and large hand bag categories will be merged into a single Hand bag category, which allows for 56x45x25 cm and a Maximum of 10 kg)

Answer (score 0):

The maximum weight is 10kg according to https://www.skyscanner.net/news/tips/wizz-air-hand-luggage-rules/

This is the expected weight limit for almost all carry on (8-10kg) from most of the companies, but usually most airlines don't bother to weight the baggage, they pay more attention to the size in order to fit in the containers